# Nameserver issue when hosting on a.n.other virtual server

Tags: nameserver

Complex question - my sites seem to work, but I've been trying to force a redirect from the non www url to the www.url ( as seems preferred for search engines) . In doing so I'm stmbling on some basics.

The site is hosted on a friends virtual server to which I have admin access. The PLESK control panel states 
"This server acts as a primary nameserver for the DNS zone xxxx.co.uk" and there are a list of MX records displayed.

But.. the site is registered by Easyspace and in the easyspace control panel, the nameserver is set to ns1.namecity.com & ns2.namecity.com .. which are easyspaces name servers. I have set the records here  to point to my virtual servers ip address.

Now maybe I should have changed the nameservers away from easyspace to my virtual servers nameserver ( whatever that is ) and not modified the Easyspace MX records at all ... ...

The sites do work however, but maybe this wasn't the right way to do it.
Once I understand what is what I'll progress onto the original issue.

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The actual nameservers will be those that you configured with the registrar.  Depending on how much you trust your friend's DNS servers, you could either update your registrar's info with those servers, leave them as is, or maybe use one of easyspace's and one of your friends.  Just know that unless you do that none of the changes you make in plesk regarding DNS will have any effect.